# Show that $f(z)$ is not differentiable at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that 
$$
f(z)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\bar{z}^2}{z}, & \text{if } z\ne0\\
0, & \text{if } z=0
\end{cases}
$$
is not differentiable at $0$.

My problem is that is satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations, so I can't use that to show that it is not analytic, and hence not differentiable. So I'm trying to show that it is not continuous instead, because non-continuity implies non-differentiability.

So I've written $f(z)$ in terms of its real part and imaginary part: $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where
$$u(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3-3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$v(x,y)=\dfrac{y^3-3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$
So all that's left to show is that $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are not continuous at $(0,0)$. And then there's my problem. How do I even do this? I tried getting the limit from different paths but they always end up equal to $0$.

This is a homework so all I need is a hint. Or if there's a better or different way of showing that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: It is continuous at zero, since $|f(z)| \le |z|$.

Comment: Your function is of the form $u(x,y) + i u(y,x)$. Are you sure it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Note that the Cauchy Riemann equations must be satisfied in a neighbourhood of zero, not just at zero (for example, $z \mapsto |z|^2$). It is easy to check that Cauchy Riemann is not satisfied nearby zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d(z)={f(z)-f(0) \over z} = ({\overline{z} \over z})^2$.

Consider the paths $z_1(t)=t$ and $z_2(t)=t(1+i)$ for real $t$.

$d(z_1(t)) = 1$, $d(z_2(t)) = -1$.

Actually, it would have been simpler just to consider $z(t) = t e^{i\theta}$, then $d(z(t)) = e^{-4i \theta}$ and the result follows since this is not a constant (as a function of $\theta$).

Comment: Oh right of course, by definition!! I didn't think of that. Thank you!!